# Replace the old token with the new generated one : refreshToken

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, .net-core, jwt

I'm using this code to generate a new Token so i can use it to replace the expirated token.
My problem is how to replace the token so i can use the new one,
for now i'm only generating a new one.

```
    public IActionResult UpdateToken(string username, List<string> ListRoles, string Listcompany)
    {
        var _db = _Context;
        string societe = null;
        var symmetricKey = _configuration["Token:Key"];
        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        ApplicationUser ap = new ApplicationUser();
        ap = _db.Users.Where(r => r.UserName.Equals(username)).FirstOrDefault();
        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
                {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Rsa, company.Name),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.PrimarySid, company.Id.ToString()),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, ap.Language),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Expiration, DateTime.Now.AddDays(20).ToString())
            }),
        };
        foreach (string role in Roles)
        {
            tokenDescriptor.Subject.AddClaims(new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role) });
        }
        var stoken = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
        var token =
                new JwtSecurityToken(issuer: _configuration["Token:Issuer"],
                                    audience: _configuration["Token:Audience"],
                                    claims: tokenDescriptor.Subject.Claims,
                                    expires: DateTime.Now.AddDays(20),
                                    notBefore: DateTime.Now,
                                    signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["Token:Key"])),
                                    SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512));
        string tokenstring = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
        try
        {
            JwtKeys key = new JwtKeys()
            {
                jwtKey = tokenstring,
                userId = ap.UserName
            };
            _db.Entry(key).State = EntityState.Added;
            _db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ed)
        {
            var cst = ed;
        }
        return Ok(tokenstring);
    }
```

Any help?
And Thaks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking here. Cannot you just forget the old token and use the new one in Angular?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto this is what i want to do.How i can use the new one in the place of the older one?

Comment: Do you mean that you do not want to manually replace the old/expired token with a new one in your front end angular code?

Comment: Well, how can i replace it manually?